# Multi-Level Modelling in Metanalysis where effect size is in percentage

Tags: meta-analysis, multilevel-analysis

I was wondering if someone can help. I have a meta-analysis where I have 5 outcomes and 10 included studies. The studies are classic prevalence/ epidemiological studies, so not 2 groups. I want to synthesize effect size for the 5 outcomes. At the moment I am conducting separate meta-analyses for each outcome’s effect size, and subsequently 5 different meta-regressions. However I have been reading a bit around MLM and I was wondering if it can be adapted to my project which is an epidemiological/prevalence study metanalysis, with outcomes in percentages, and just 1 group. I have 10 studies in this meta-analysis and 5 outcomes that I am looking at. With each study reporting on at at least 3 out of the 5, and some reporting all 5 out of 5 outcomes.

Comment: It would certainly be possible. It would probably be easier if you have estimates of the correlations between outcomes.

Comment: @mdewey do you know of any papers where they have done this? I cannot seem to come across any....

Comment: Unfortunately I do not.